# Minimum how much bitcoin may I get per week if I stake 0.05BTC?

Tags: bitcoin-core, proof-of-stake

If I keep my pc on for 17 hours a day, then minimum how much bitcoin may I get per week if I stake 0.05BTC ?

-Thanks.

Comment: Since Bitcoin is not a proof-of-stake cryptocurrency, this question is unclear.  What exactly is your computer doing for 17 hr/day?  How is the 0.05BTC being used to earn more bitcoin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin uses pure PoW (proof of work) mining, so you can't really "stake" your 0.05BTC. The only thing that will determine how much bitcoin you may get, will be your computing power, measured in hashes per second h/s (or kh/s, Mh/s, Gh/s...).

If you solo-mine, finding a block with a PC is like winning the lottery, so chances are you'd never get any bitcoin.
To get some, you'd want to join a mining pool, where the winnings are distributed among participants, proportional to their hashrate.

However, note that the era of CPU/GPU mining is long gone, and specialized hardware now exists, multiple times more powerful than your average CPU/GPU (at least when measured in h/s). So, even if you join a pool, with your PC, you can't really get any significant amount of BTC.

There are many sites which can calculate mining profitability for you, one example [here](http://www.vnbitcoin.org/bitcoincalculator.php).

Comment: thanks for the information, could you please tell me which is the most profitable proof of stake coin now ?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea as I don't really follow any of those coins, sorry. I take it it's easier to be profitable with PoS, as you don't have to spend your resources (electricity).

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin is not POS. POS usully has a reward specified for each currency. So you will have to see the corresponding currency for it.